# PHP array: get first not empty value no matter the key

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array with strings that are user's comments

The array can be like this:

```
//example 1    
   $comments
    : array = 
      0: string = 
      1: string = 
      2: string = this is one comment
```

Or like this:

```
//example 2  
    $comments
    : array = 
      0: string = hey, I am a comment
      1: string = 
      2: string = 
      3: string = and this is another comment
```

Or any other form containing empty strings and comments

What I need is an string with the firs not empty comment.

In example 1 the string should contain: "this is one comment"

And in example 2 "hey, I am a comment"

How can I do that? I am going round and round this and it has to be much more simple.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: How come you end up with empty comments in the first place?

Comment: `array_filter($comments)[0];`

Comment: thanks but array_filter maintains the key and in Example 1, the key is 2 not 0

Comment: *get first not empty value* or get key of the first not empty value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using a forloop instead:

```
<?php

$ex1 = array("", "", "comment");
$ex2 = array("comment", "", "");

function getFirstNotEmpty($arr) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
        if (!empty($arr[$i]))
            return $arr[$i];
}

echo getFirstNotEmpty($ex1) . "\n";
echo getFirstNotEmpty($ex2);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/30f654464751d1):

```
comment
comment
```

Answer (score 0):

and if your PHP version can't dereference...

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(trim($value)) return $value;
}
return "No comments found";
```